# Trying to create a single array of objects from two three returned from API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have a project where in one instance I am returning an object that contains three separate arrays of objects.

Like so...

```
[
   Array 1:[
    { key: value}
   ],
   Array 2:[
    { key: value},
    { key: value}
   ],
   Array 2:[
    { key: value},
    { key: value}
   ]
]
```

What I'm trying to do is take this multi array of objects and make it a single array containing the objects from all three.

I'm trying to do this using angular.forEach and loop through them and push them into a new array, but it's not working.

```
var newArray = [];

angular.forEach(result, function(value, key){
   newArray.push(value);
});

return newArray;
```

Could really use some advice on this one!

Thanks!

Comment: [
   [
    { key: value}
   ],
   [
    { key: value},
    { key: value}
   ],
   [
    { key: value},
    { key: value}
   ]
] Is this your result array?

Comment: The array dont seems to be in proper format

Answer (score 4):

You can use `concat()` and spread syntax.

```js
var arr = [[{ key: 'value'}],[{ key: 'value'},{ key: 'value'}],[{ key: 'value'},{ key: 'value'}]]

var result = [].concat(...arr);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Most elegant solution ever.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` method, which accepts a `callback` provided function.

```js
var arr = [[{ key: 'value'}],[{ key: 'value'},{ key: 'value'}],[{ key: 'value'},{ key: 'value'}]]

var array = arr.reduce(function(obj,item){
    obj.push(...item);
    return obj;
},[]);
console.log(array)
```